# Display Image in Original Resolution Android

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I have an Image of size 129px × 1579px and i want it to be displayed without being scaled! (as it is).

I tried displaying using `ImageView` placing the image in drawable folder, `drawable-nodpi` folder but it is always scaled!

I even tried displaying it using a `WebView` yet the rendered HTML page is scaled depending upon different screen sizes!

None seems to work.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#444444"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ruler" />
 </ScrollView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Question : "is these a way i can display the image that i have 'as it is'?

**Update :**

The image is a Ruler so it has to be rendered correctly (as it is)

[image: Ruler]

Thanks

Comment: try wrap_content in your layouts.

Comment: You need full size image with scrolling, Right?

Comment: @Ammar yes ... u have a ScrollView enclosing the ImageView

Comment: @Developer try setting layout_width/layout_height to wrap_content for LinearLayout too.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of what result you are getting with Scale CENTER and drawable-nodpi to clear what is not working for you?

Comment: @Raanan i just added a snapshot.

Comment: Are we seeing the whole picture here? or is it cropped? what's the screen size?

You know that the pixels will have a different size on each screen so keeping the image pixel size will not give you a correct "meter size"?

Comment: No this is not the whole picture ... its within a `ScrollView`. Yes i know, all i want to achieve is the image should be displayed without being scaled on all devices!

Answer (score 0):

Placing the Image in drawable or drawable-nodpi will prevent the scaling according to device dpi.

Set the ImageView scaling to CENTER - this will prevent scaling by the ImageView
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html
add this to you ImageView:

```
android:scaleType="center"
```

Comment: android:scaleType="center" didnt help!

Comment: Yes.. its in drawable-nodpi. P.S : I have tried almost everything available on stackoverflow none seems to help.

Comment: To solve your issue you will need to combine at least these two solutions (IMO they should do the trick).